# Colour points in X,Y scatter based on value of continuous data in another column

Tags: gnuplot, graphing

My question is similar to this one:
[vary point color based on column value for multiple data blocks gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427704/vary-point-color-based-on-column-value-for-multiple-data-blocks-gnuplot)

Except there was not an explanation given above for the syntax used and what it meant..

The data looks like this - columns separated by a comma and enter separates rows:

```
0,       0F_0F_0F_0F_0F,  0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0,     1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0 

4.046025985,     0F_2Fo_0F_2Fo_0F,  0_0_1_0_0_0_0_0_1_0,     1_1_0_0_0_0_1_0_0_0 

2.941144083,     0F_0F_0F_0F_0F,  0_0_1_0_0_1_0_0_0_1,     1_0_0_0_1_0_0_0_0_0 

1.836301245,     0F_0F_0F_2Fo_0F, 0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0,     1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0 

0.90317579,      0F_0F_0F_2Fo_0F,  0_0_0_1_0_0_0_1_0_0,     1_0_1_0_0_1_0_0_1_0 

3.826663156,     0F_0F_0F_0F_0F,  0_1_0_0_1_0_1_0_0_1,     1_0_1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0
```

In my datafile, there are 100 individual rows, where column 1 is to be used for the colour palette and columns 2-4 are labels for X,Y axes on two different plots

What I want is an X,Y scatter of columns 3 and 4, with column 1 used to colour each point on the plot.

Here is my script attempt:

```
set title "K and W Occupancy \n KcsA, Replica 0, 0 mV "

set xlabel "POT" font ",18"
set ylabel "Water" font ",18"
set cblabel "Free energy (kT)" font ",18"

set xtics rotate by -45
set xtics out font ", 13" nomirror
set ytics out font ", 13" nomirror
set pointsize 0.4

set xrange [0:100]
iset yrange [0:100]
set cbrange [0:10]

# MATLAB jet color pallete --> from https://github.com/Gnuplotting/gnuplot-palettes/blob/master/jet.pal
# palette
set palette defined (0  0.0 0.0 0.5, \
                     1  0.0 0.0 1.0, \
                     2  0.0 0.5 1.0, \
                     3  0.0 1.0 1.0, \
                     4  0.5 1.0 0.5, \
                     5  1.0 1.0 0.0, \
                     6  1.0 0.5 0.0, \
                     7  1.0 0.0 0.0, \
                     8  0.5 0.0 0.0 )

splot '$filename' using 3:4:($1 <= 10 ?  0 : 1) w p pointtype 5 pointsize 1 palette linewidth 10
```

I do not really know what this means:
($1 <= 10 ?  0 : 1)

Why does the script plot a 3D graph with the data incorrectly placed?

Was expected a 2D plot with unique entries along the X and Y axes, with each point coloured along a colour scale..

The attempt described above results in a 3D plot and the points are incorrect.

Multiple answers to similar questions I have read do not explain what each term in the gnuplot script means, including:

[Plotting style based on an entry in a data-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275261/plotting-style-based-on-an-entry-in-a-data-file)

[gnuplot splot colors based on a fourth column of the data file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622820/gnuplot-splot-colors-based-on-a-fourth-column-of-the-data-file)

[vary point color based on column value for multiple data blocks gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427704/vary-point-color-based-on-column-value-for-multiple-data-blocks-gnuplot)

Comment: What are these strings in column 2 to 4? Should this be hexadecimal or binary numbers? How do you want to get to x,y coordinates for plotting? Please clarify!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have your data (if possible please always add minimized data) and we don't see your graph output.

> I do not really know what this means: ($1 <= 10 ? 0 : 1)

This is the ternary operator. Check `help ternary`. If the value in column 1 (`$1`) is smaller or equal to 10 return `0`, and `1` otherwise.

> Why does the script plot a 3D graph with the data incorrectly placed?

Because you told gnuplot so. Mind the difference `splot` and `plot`. Check `help splot` and `help plot`. `splot` requires x,y,z input and your z is `($1 <= 10 ?  0 : 1)`

So, without being able to test your case, your command probably should be something like this:

```
plot '$filename' u 3:4:1 w p pt 5 ps 1 lc palette
```

**Addition:**

If I understood your question correctly, I guess there is no off-the-self plotting style for this.

You need to:

- create lists of unique elements (by (mis-)using `stats`, check `help stats`) for x and for y (in your case column 3 and 4). The list will be in the order of occurrence in the datafile. Unfortunately, gnuplot does not offer an internal alphanumerical sort of a list. If you want it sorted you need to either use external tools or a [cumbersome gnuplot-only workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54245537/7295599).
- define a function by (mis-)using `sum` (check `help sum`) which determines the index of a given item and use this index either as x- or y-coordinate

**Script:**

```
### scatter plot with x,y strings
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.00,   0F_0F_0F,   0_0_0_0,   0_0_0_0
0.43,   0F_0F_0F,   0_1_1_1,   1_0_1_1
0.64,   0F_0F_0F,   0_1_1_1,   1_1_0_0
0.73,   0F_0F_0F,   0_1_1_1,   0_1_1_1
0.29,   0F_0F_0F,   0_1_0_1,   1_0_1_1
0.34,   0F_0F_0F,   0_1_0_1,   1_1_1_1
0.45,   0F_0F_0F,   1_1_1_1,   1_0_1_1
0.10,   0F_0F_0F,   1_1_1_1,   0_1_1_1
0.99,   0F_0F_0F,   0_0_1_1,   1_1_0_0
EOD

uniqX = uniqY = ' '
addToList(uniq,col) = uniq.(strstrt(uniq,' '.strcol(col).' ') ? '' : strcol(col).' ' )

getIdx(list,s) = (_c=NaN, sum[_i=1:words(list)] (word(list,_i) eq s ? _c=_i : NaN) , _c)

set datafile separator comma
stats $Data u (uniqX=addToList(uniqX,3), uniqY=addToList(uniqY,4)) nooutput

set key noautotitle
set xtic noenhanced rotate by 90 right
set ytic noenhanced
set offsets 0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5
set bmargin 4
set size ratio -1
set grid x,y
set palette rgb 33,13,10

plot $Data u (getIdx(uniqX,strcol(3))):(getIdx(uniqY,strcol(4))):1:xtic(3):ytic(4) w p pt 5 ps 7 lc palette
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Appreciate the help. Have updated the question to include the data

Comment: @BillyNoonan so, does it work? Then please check the check mark at the top left of the answer indicating that the question is answered.

Comment: Thank you again for the help. No, it does not work - question not answered. The X and Y axis labels are strings if that provides enough information?

Comment: @BillyNoonan Ok, now you see how important it is to add data! What are these strings? Hexadecimal or binary numbers? How should the strings be translated into a number, i.e. x,y? Please clarify!

Comment: Hi @theozh - sorry for the late reply, it was late where I am in the world. The strings are binary, but only some combinations of 0s and 1s are physically possible (~30 unique strings out of the 100 datapoints). I have generated a list of unique strings from my data. Unfortunately, I cannot give more information than that.. If I label the X-tics, will that fix the problem?

Comment: @BillyNoonan ok, strange binary strings. However, the "binary" strings in row 1 and 4 (and column 3 and 4) are identical. How do you want plot this? Two values on top of each other and the later one wins?

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer - yes that answers the question :-)